# how to swap 'recipient' from one action to another in Docusign - Using API

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to docusignAPI and currently trying to solve, if there is a way to swap user from one action type to another. 
For example: I can initially have someone assigned as "Acknowledge Recipient". I am tryin to see if it is possible through API to move the same recipient to "Signer".

I am able to do this from UI when i create an envelope. I can click on "correct" and make changes.

But when i try to do this by API i am not able to achieve it. I guess i miss some best way due to my very limited knowledge on the API.

Have someone tried this before. If so can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change Recipient Type using the API.  From page 159 of the DocuSign REST API Guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf):

```
Once an envelope has been sent, you can only edit: email, userName, signerName, routingOrder, faxNumber, and deliveryMethod.
```

So, changing a recipient's type would likely be a two-step process with the API:

1. ADD recipient (with new type) to the envelope:  `POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`
2. DELETE recipient (with old/original type) from the envelope:  `DELETE /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients`

I'd suggest doing things in this order (adding first, then deleting) so that the Envelope won't advance (to future recipients) in the workflow until that recipient completes their required action.